# What happened to bitcoin-24?

Tags: exchanges

As per subject. It has been down for some days, apparently due to bank problems of the owner(s):

> Our Service is momentarily not available.
>    1. All funds (EUR, USD, PLN, GBP & Bitcoins) are safe.
>    2. All withdrawals will be gradually processed chronologically from another bank account.
>    3. The Polish authority closed our Bank account in Poland.
>    4. Our lawyers are working with high pressure on a solution.
>
> We will back with Bitcoin-24 2.0 on when all declarations are
>   finished.
>
> All important Emails can be send to help@bitcoin-24.com

Doesn anyone have more information?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1c8yqr/scary_stackoverflow_question_from_bitcoin24s_admin/?sort=old&limit=500 **Oh. My. God.**
= One would think that a guy operating an online trading system would at least know the basis about rounding... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165559/how-to-round-amounts-correct-update-1 Or, *at the very least*, what a database transaction is...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026825/php-mysql-how-to-prevent-two-requests-update I repeat: **Oh. My. God.**
=

Comment: `One would think that a guy operating an online trading system would at least know the basis about rounding` Actually, if you think about it, there isn't any reason to round numbers in an automated trading system unless you're showing amounts to the user.

Comment: Or to store them as floating point numbers. Or to program *any* kind of DB stuff without knowing what a transaction is. *Especially* if you manage money with it. This just looks so awfully... *amateurish*.

Answer (score 0):

From the website:

```
Update 28. April
BTC withdrawals are now enabled.
All withdrawals will be done manually within 24 Hours.

Your password must be reset with the following link: reset password

For support please use our Ticket-System
```